# declaring and assigning variable

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment, declaration

This class has a variable called Paraula and I'm having trouble when I assign a value to it.

```
public Paraula() {
lletres = new char[MAXIM];
llargaria = 0;
}

public static Paraula llegir() {
Paraula nova = new Paraula();
botarBlancs();
while ((lletra != fiSequencia) && // No ha acabat la seqüència
        (lletra != blanc)) { // Hi ha prou espai
    nova.lletres[nova.llargaria++] = lletra;
    lletra = leerCarTeclado();
}
return nova;
}

public String toString() {
String msg = "";
for (int idx = 0; idx < llargaria; idx++) {
    msg += lletres[idx];
}
return msg;
}

public boolean esIgualA(Paraula b) {
boolean iguals = llargaria == b.llargaria;
for (int idx = 0; (idx < llargaria) && iguals; idx++) {
    iguals = lletres[idx] == b.lletres[idx];
}
return iguals;
}

public static boolean iguals(Paraula a, Paraula b) {
return a.esIgualA(b);
}

public boolean buida() {
return llargaria == 0;
}

public static void botarBlancs() {
while (lletra == blanc) {
    lletra = leerCarTeclado();
}
}

public static void botarParaula() throws Exception {
while ((lletra != '.') && (lletra != blanc)) {
    lletra = leerCarTeclado();
}
}
static public char leerCarTeclado() {
char res = '.';
if (frase != null) {
    res = frase[indice++];
}
return res;
}
```

I want to declare two Paraula variables called: tipo (using method llegir() that reads from a sequence of characters) and tipo1:

```
Paraula tipo;
        tipo = Paraula.llegir();

              Paraula tipo1;
              tipo1  = {   
              Paraula.lletres[0] = 't';
              Paraula.lletres[1]='1';
              Paraula.llargaria = 2;
       }
```

When I declare tipo1 it reports an illegal start of expression. What's wrong with the code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing the following which id not valid Java,

```
          Paraula tipo1;
          tipo1  = {   
          Paraula.lletres[0] = 't';
          Paraula.lletres[1]='1';
          Paraula.llargaria = 2;
```

perhaps you intended to write

```
          Paraula tipo1 = new Paraula();
          tipo1.lletres[0] = 't';
          tipo1.lletres[1]='1';
          tipo1.llargaria = 2;
```

However a much cleaner way to do this is to pass a String to the constructor

```
  Paraula tipo1 = new Paraula("t1");
```

Where your constructor is

```
public Paraula(String s) {
    lletres = s.toCharArray();
    llargaria = lletres.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I declare tipo1 it reports an illegal start of expression. What's wrong with the code?

The code you writed its invalid for java. Try this way:

```
Paraula tipo1 = new Paraula();
tipo1.lletres[0] = 't';
tipo1.lletres[1] = '1';
tipo1.llargaria = 2;
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what the original problem was, and so doesn't help the asker avoid it in the future.

Comment: Code was invalid, added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't properly initializing `tipo1`. To define a new `Paraula` object, you need to call a constructor. (`tipo` is initialized alright, but that isn't really proper either). Consider a constructor like:

```
public Paraula(char[] c, int i) {
    lletres = c;
    llargaria = i;
}
```

tipo1 initialization

```
tipo1 = new Paraula(new char[]{'t','1'}, 2);
```